# Redirecting DNS to localhost in a cgroup

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, dns, iptables

I'm trying to make use of `cgroups` to force certain applications to bypass my VPN. While it is working for the most part I'm having a little trouble with DNS queries.

The VPN configures only the `filter` table:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [7374:4303108]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6573:2344795]
:xvpn - [0:0]
:xvpn_dns - [0:0]
:xvpn_dns_iface_exceptions - [0:0]
:xvpn_dns_ip_exceptions - [0:0]
:xvpn_ks - [0:0]
:xvpn_ks_iface_exceptions - [0:0]
:xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions - [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -j xvpn
-A xvpn -j xvpn_dns
-A xvpn -j xvpn_ks
-A xvpn_dns -j xvpn_dns_iface_exceptions
-A xvpn_dns -j xvpn_dns_ip_exceptions
-A xvpn_dns ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DROP
-A xvpn_dns_ip_exceptions -d 10.63.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A xvpn_ks -j xvpn_ks_iface_exceptions
-A xvpn_ks -j xvpn_ks_ip_exceptions
```

With my limited understanding, I see that it should allow queries to both `lo` and `10.63.0.1`. The VPN also configures `/etc/resolv.conf`. I have `dnsmasq` running locally and would like non VPN traffic to use it.

I'm setting up my `cgroup` with:

```bsh
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 \
    -j MARK --set-mark 11
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -p udp --dport 53 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -o enp6s0 \
    -j MASQUERADE

ip rule add fwmark 11 table novpn
ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 table novpn
```

DNS queries from the cgroup are not resolving. However, if I modify the filter table to accept, it will work.

```bsh
iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -j ACCEPT
```

I'm guessing, but may be wrong, that even though the packets destination IP has changed from `10.63.0.1` (coming from /etc/resolv.conf) to `127.0.0.1`, it is still using the target interface of `enp6s0` rather than `lo`. I don't know how to confirm this.

I'd like to be able connect/disconnect my VPN, which overwrites the filter table each time, without affecting the cgroup traffic. How can I do this? Is there any way to set the DNS query to use `lo` before entering the filter table?